# Hide View other than Gone

Tags: java, android

Does anyone know if a way to hide a view other than View.Gone and View.Invisible?

```
if (isAvailable) {
        layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

I'm dynamically setting one fragment to show up and disappear in the view and View.Gone and View.Invisible leave behind a space, sometimes, and also looks like they are glitching with fragments and action bar, making fragment content disappear.

Comment: You can change alpha of your view. But I suppose it's better to solve problems with `glitching` and `extra space`.

Comment: According to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE gone should NOT leave behind a space. Are you sure that you properly set the position of the other elements?

Comment: Could it be that somekind of caching is enableling it then? I'm seeing first round everything is fine but afterwards it leaves space.

Answer (score 0):

There are no any other option to hide view

you can use below parameters only

```
View.setVisibility(View.GONE / View.VISIBLE / View.INVISIBLE)
```

Answer (score 0):

View.GONE will cause the layout to refresh without leaving space for that view.  Make sure the fragment container is set to wrap_content and that other views are properly configured for dynamic sizing.  If you post your XML we may be able to give you a more specific answer.